# How to reprompt for IOS app for push notifications

Tags: ios, notifications

My app uses push notifications.  If the user says no to push notifications when they install the app, but then a few days later decides they want push notifications, how do I program that option in the app in a settings? Do I just call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes (actually AppDelegate does this every time the app is stated) ?

Comment: You don't, the iOS SDk will only ask the question once. If the user said no then your only option is the present a UIAlertView explaining that they can change this in the settings.app

Comment: General -> setting -> notification center then on

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The user has to go into settings on the device and allow notifications there.

You can see if notifications are enabled with the `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` property of `UIApplication` and prompt the user to go to settings, but this would be incredibly spammy. You'd be better off having some text in a settings screen.